# Twitters Card-Validator error: Failed to fetch page due to: OutOfHop

Tags: twitter, twitter-card

Up until a couple of days ago our Twitter-Card was working fine and it was already approved.

Now, finally our iPhone App was approved and is available on the AppStore and I wanted to give the twitter-share feature a test-run and was surprised to see that our card was not working.

I entered the URL https://beatclip.com/player/?v=91D51A035FB24114B7CC04A19E878965 in the Card-Validator and receive the following, not very helpful Error-Message:

```
ERROR: Failed to fetch page due to: OutOfHop
```

Unfortunately neither google nor the documentation or forum was of any help.

Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

It was a redirect-loop caused by our I18N wordpress-plugin